# Is there any indication in more than one movie that Stan Laurel has magical powers?

Tags: laurel-and-hardy

In Block-Heads, we see Stan do some things, innocent himself of the fact that he is doing anything unusual, that are supernatural -- this is the sort of cartoonish theme that being unaware that something is impossible, a naïve character is able to do it. We see specifically him interact with a shadow of a shade, pulling it down so that indeed no sunlight is then on a wall (he does this more than once but Hardy is unable to do this). Shortly thereafter he materializes a glass of water and then an ice cube.

I think I must have seen many of their films in the distant past and I can't recall anything like that occurring. But is there at least one other L&H film in which L displays this sort of ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Way Out West (1937)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029747/)
Stan several times uses his thumb as a lighter, for a pipe & several candles.
This *unique* magic, though is later broken because Ollie eventually manages to do the same thing.

There is no explanation at all - in keeping with most things they do which would otherwise be considered remarkable.

Nicely compiled into one short video…

<sup>These last two are different timestamps to the same video compilation. I don't know specifically which movies they're from.</sup>

He keeps a glass of water & ice cubes in his pockets

He smokes his clenched fist like a pipe, including a match that lights several seconds after he strikes it [twice]…

Comment: Thanks, as I said, despite watching their films often (maybe there was some channel when I was a youngster that showed them regularly) no memory of this. I wonder if this was some old Vaudeville (or the English equivalent) gag that Stan saw or originated in his live performances.

Comment: Yeah, remembering the 'thumb lighter' led me to some of the others, most of which I did remember once my memory was jogged. When I was a kid [50 years ago or so] they were a constant Saturday morning TV filler, so I've probably seen them all at one time or another. There's no doubt he was a great physical comedian, but idk where these tricks may have originated. The thumb lighter needs a cut-away to swap in the wax thumb by the looks of it.

Comment: More bizarre question: would this be on topic at SF&F?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that's a toughie. It's not sci-fi… is it fantasy? Is it even 'magic' per se? There's a certain innocence in the execution of these gags which could be 'fantastic', but it's injected into otherwise quite mundane [in its original sense of 'earthly', not 'boring'] plots that have exceptional turns for the characters involved.